# OpenSeaDragon Zoom in working only 3 levels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deepzoom, openseadragon

DeepZoom is creating 12 levels of images. Here my problem is when i click the zoom in ,it works only 3 times. I cannot go depth of zooming. starting Level 10 to Level 12.  Is it possible create more DeepZoom images or create custom code for more zooming to add ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct relationship between the levels of tiles created versus how many times you can click to zoom in. It all depends on how big your viewer is and how big your image is. If you want to be able to zoom further into your image, perhaps you need a bigger image. You can also use the `maxZoomPixelRatio` option when creating the viewer to allow zooming further (though the image will get blurry when you zoom past full resolution); for instance, try `maxZoomPixelRatio: 2` (the default is 1.1).

Comment: Thanks. I changed one more thing. in openseadragon.min.js ,  DEFAULT_SETTINGS part  minZoomLevel: 1, maxZoomLevel: 100. The zooming in depth. but image is blurred.

Comment: You don't need to modify openseadragon.min.js directly; use those values when you create the OpenSeadragon viewer instead. And yes, the image will be blurred if there is not enough detail. You need to make a more high resolution image to start with.